# Styling Hidden Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've got **Dynamic Dropdown** that will show **another two hidden dropdown** when selected. I'm using this dropdown on a form. Unfortunately, I do not know how to style the dropdown accordingly. I've tried css and html styling method but nothing happened. I've try to search online but to no avail.

This is what they looked like :

Not arranged and no space between each other.

[image: here]

I wanted them to be like this :

Arranged in one straight line and have space between them.

[image: this]

This is my dropdown code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Administration</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  

<script type="text/javascript" src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Agency").change(function(){

//To remove all the dropdown in myDiv
$('#myDiv').html('');

//Create the new dropdown menu
var whereToPut1 = document.getElementById('myDiv');//Department dropdown
var newDropdown1 = document.createElement('select');
newDropdown1.setAttribute('id',"newDropdownMenu");
whereToPut1.appendChild(newDropdown1);

//Create another div inside myDiv for another dropdown menu
var innerDropdowndiv = document.createElement('div');
innerDropdowndiv.setAttribute('id',"innerdropdowndiv");
whereToPut1.appendChild(innerDropdowndiv);
var whereToPut2 = document.getElementById('innerdropdowndiv');

//Create another dropdown menu
var newDropdown2 = document.createElement('select');//Office dropdown
newDropdown2.setAttribute('id',"innerDropdownMenu");
whereToPut2.appendChild(newDropdown2);

if ($('#Agency').find(":selected").text() == "PPS") {
                $('#newDropdownMenu').append('<option id="Department">Department</option>')//Department dropdown appear
                $('#newDropdownMenu').append('<option>Office</option>')//Office dropdown will appear below Department
                $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>HQ</option>')
                $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>Branch</option>')
                $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>Stall</option>')

                $("#newDropdownMenu").change(function(){
                    if($('#newDropdownMenu').find(":selected").text() == "Department")
                    {
                      $('#innerdropdowndiv').html('');
                      $('#innerdropdowndiv').append($('<select>').attr('id','innerDropdownMenu'))
                      $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>HQ</option>')
                      $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>Branch</option>')
                      $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>Stall</option>')
                    }
                    else if($('#newDropdownMenu').find(":selected").text() == "Office" && $('#innerDropdownMenu').find(":selected").text()=="Branch")
                    {
                      $('#innerdropdowndiv').html('');
                      $('#innerdropdowndiv').append($('<select>').attr('id','innerDropdownMenu'))
                      $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>Floor1</option>')
                      $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>Floor2</option>')
                    }
                    else if($('#newDropdownMenu').find(":selected").text() == "Office" && $('#innerDropdownMenu').find(":selected").text()=="Stall")
                    {
                      $('#innerdropdowndiv').html('');
                      $('#innerdropdowndiv').append($('<select>').attr('id','innerDropdownMenu'))
                      $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>Floor3</option>')
                      $('#innerDropdownMenu').append('<option>Floor4</option>')
                    }
                    else {
                      {
                        $('#innerdropdowndiv').html('');
                      }
                    }
                })
              }
else {
      $('#myDiv').html('');
}
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<td class = "Agency">Agency<span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
     <tr><td><select id="Agency"">
        <option value="Choose">Choose</option>
        <option value="SPM">SPM</option>
        <option value="PPS">PPS</option>
        </select>
        <h></h>
        </td>
         <td>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
        </td>

        <td><div id="innerdropdowndiv"></div></td>
     </tr>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: The down arrow is an unicode or image?
If an image, please share the same!

Comment: @Keerthana the down arrow = options. They got several option on each dropdown

Comment: the default one. alright.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table structure is not correct and please see the below updated code. Find the JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsachin/v9zaLxqc/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'>
```

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="Agency">
  Agency<span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</td>
<td>
  <select id="Agency">
    <option value='Choose'>Choose</option>
    <option value='SPM'>SPM</option>
    <option value='PPS'>PPS</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
  <div id='myDiv'>
  </div>
</td>
<tr>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div id="innerdropdowndiv"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RanjitSachin but how do i create space between them ? I've tried `<br>` but nothing happened.

Comment: If you need space between dropdown, then you can use margin. Already I used and you can inrease that. OR are you need space within select box. You can use padding for that, Please see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsachin/v9zaLxqc/3/

Comment: Thank you sir @RanjitKumar I'll try to apply your method on mine.

Comment: I need your help in figuring out how to add the label of hidden dropdown @RanjitKumar

Comment: My suggestion is keep select box and label in html only and show / hide those select box and label based on your requirement, I will add the jsfiddle soon.

Comment: Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsachin/v9zaLxqc/8/

Comment: I'll try your code on mine. Thank you sir @RanjitKumar

Comment: Can you please help me figure out why the code did not function when I add another option on Department ? The option on Floor won't change. I try to change it accordingly to what I needed. Please check this : https://jsfiddle.net/Farr/m9509zus/  @RanjitKumar

Comment: Please see the line no. 15 and 20. You added two curly open braces and remove one. It will work properly.